# jQuery + head.js: How to trigger $(document).ready() manually from inside ready callback of head.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, head.js

I need to optimize the load time of a web application which contains lots of javascript files included in each of it's HTML pages. I want to try [head.js](http://headjs.com) in one such page to see if it improves load time. There are lots of `$(document).ready(callback)` callbacks in those JS files which are invoked when DOM is loaded while head.js is still downloading remaining JS files.

Is there a way I could tell jQuery not to trigger `ready` event on its own, rather let me trigger it from inside the ready callback of head.js?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but looks like people don't use head.js with jQuery frequently.

Comment: Any ideas people? Any suggestions? Even loud thinking will be much appreciated!

Comment: On their page they mention this problem, and they say jQuery 1.4+ works. What version of jQuery do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure as to why you'd want to trigger the document ready event manually.

Instead, subscribe and publish your own events using jQuery's built-in `trigger` & `bind` functionality. This is best practice and the optimal solution.

**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/ZLqJ9/1/)**

Comment: Since head.js downloads JS files in parallel without blocking other things, jQuery's ready would trigger when many of the JS files haven't yet downloaded, thus breaking the code.

Comment: Did you see my JSFiddle? The `docAndHeadJSReady` event is not fired until head.js has finished loading everything.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as I mentioned, it was a legacy code I was dealing with, which had tons of code in lots of ready callbacks. There would have had been no problem at all if I could change the code at first place.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small experiment. Something like:

```
<html> 
<head>
<script src="head.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function() {
    console.log("ready.document");
});
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
head.js("a.js", "b.js", "c.js", "test.js", function() {
        console.log("init.scripts");
        var millis = 2000;
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;

        do {curDate = new Date(); } 
            while(curDate-date < millis);
        jQuery("#ddd").text(testTT);
        console.log("init.end");

});

</script>
... a lot of html content ...
<div id="ddd"></div>
...
<script type="text/javascript" >
console.log("last line");
</script>
</body>
```

The test.js writes to console and defines **testTT**. The result is following

```
last line
init.testTT
init.scripts
init.end
ready.document
```

Thus, in this simple case (using jQuery 1.8), first the code in loaded *.js is executed then head.js on init event is generated, finally jQuery ready event is generated. So it should be fine to wait until JQuery generates ready event. 
However if this is still an issue you could do the following.

```
head.js("a.js", "b.js", "c.js", function() { 
 jQuery("document").ready(function() {
      jQuery("body").trigger("your_event");
 });
});
```

and instead of listening to `jQuery("document").ready...` in your *.js start listen to the custom event you are triggering `jQuery("body").on("your_event", handler)`.

Answer (score 0):

create a function register it in document ready

`$(document).ready(readyFunc);`

```
readyFunction(){
   /// something to do;
}
```

if you like to use them manually, just need call the readyFunction();